# Which Version of Zend is better for Beginner?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Hello I am new to the Zend & Stacjoverflow also.

I have just basic concepts of Zend in mind only. So please suggest me which version is better for the development zend2 (or) Zend 1.+.

Currently i am using zend 1.12.3 only

Comment: possible duplicate of [Zend Framework 1 vs Zend Framework 2 performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314300/zend-framework-1-vs-zend-framework-2-performance)

Comment: Zend2 as learning old concepts is a bit pointless

Comment: ZF1 & ZF2 are with different architecture. In most of the cases, there must be a good reason for newer version. Thus, always use new version.

Comment: Thanks @Raptor & vogomatix. I here that zend2 is much slow compared to the zend1 is it correct?

Comment: performance depends on usage & sub version. It's better to try it out on your own.

Comment: ZF2 Apps can be much(!) faster than zf1 apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from the official [FAQs](http://framework.zend.com/about/faq/) of Zend Framework 2:

```
I’m starting a new project – which version of Zend Framework should I use?

Start using Zend Framework 2! It's already stable.
```

It is always a good idea to learn(and use) newer version.

Comment: 'New is always better' Barney Stinson.